# Java Object Array, asking for two different inputs?

Tags: java

So here is my test class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            Film[] f = new Film[10];
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                f[i] = new Film(); 

                System.out.println("Enter Title:");
                f[i].setTitle(input.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Enter Film Length:");
                f[i].setLength(input.nextDouble());
            }
        }

    }
```

I have getter and setter methods in my object class Film. The problem here is that the output comes out as:

```
Enter Title:
title1
Enter Film Length:
1
Enter Title:
Enter Film Length:
2
Enter Title:
Enter Film Length:
3
Enter Title:
Enter Film Length:
```

How would I fix my code so that it asks for 10 user inputted titles and lengths and at the end display all the film titles and lengths?

Thanks.

*I also have a toString method:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Title: "+title+" Length: "+length;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code skips to ask titles after two iterations because you use **nextLine()** to get titles. You have to use **next()** in this case.

In your code, if the first **input.nextDouble()** receives, for example,

```
1\n
```

then, **nextDouble()** only takes the value "1" and the "\n" is passed to **nextLine()** of the second iteration.

Finally, **nextLine()** reads "\n" as a new line, and **nextDouble()** is immediately executed in the second iteration and after.

The whole revised code is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Film[] f = new Film[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            f[i] = new Film();

            System.out.println("Enter Title:");
            f[i].setTitle(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter Film Length:");
            f[i].setLength(input.nextDouble());
        }
        input.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(f[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Film {
    private String title;
    private double length;
    public Film() {

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Title: "+title+" Length: "+length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first for loop, write:

```
for(Film currentFilm : f)
{
    System.out.println(currentFilm);
}
```

i.e.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Film[] f = new Film[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            f[i] = new Film(); 

            System.out.println("Enter Title:");
            f[i].setTitle(input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Enter Film Length:");
            f[i].setLength(input.nextDouble());
        }

        for(Film currentFilm : f)
        {
            System.out.println(currentFilm);
        }
    }

}
```